# Mystery line break appears when outputting JavaScript with PHP.

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, shadowbox

I am outputting some JavaScript using PHP for a WordPress shortcode.  My php looks like this:

```
$output="<script type='text/javascript' >
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#photo{$photo_id}').on('click', function(){ 
      Shadowbox.open({
        content: '<div id=\'popup{$photo_id}\' class=\'popup\'>{$content}</div>',
        player:     'html',
        height:     500,
        width:      1200,
        handleOversize: 'drag'
        }); 
    });
});       
</script>";

return $output;
```

but the output has a line break after the first quotation mark in the content arguement for Shadowbox.

like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#stylistphoto1').on('click', function(){    
      Shadowbox.open({
        content: '
<div> id=\'popup1\' class=\'popup\'> . . .
```

which is giving me an "unterminated string literal" error and making my script fail.

What is going on?

Notes: 
a. This is encoded in UTF-8 Without BOM.
b. This did work at one point.
c. It works just fine if I pass an empty string as the content arguement, which, of course, doesn't help me at all.

Comment: I ran your code on my machine (windows XAMPP php 5.3.8) and the output seems fine, no unexpected linebrakes anywhere...

Comment: Thanks PeterVR.  Unfortunately I cannot do the same yet, even with the suggestions mentioned below.

Comment: did you try the code I provided verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't define javascript functionality in a php variable and then echo somewhere, it's a very bad practice.

The problem here may be that something on your styling is line breaking that line because it's pretty long. What you could do to fix this is do the following:

```
$output="<script type='text/javascript' >
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#photo{$photo_id}').on('click', function(){ 
      Shadowbox.open({
        content: '<div id=\'popup{$photo_id}\' ' +
                 'class=\'popup\'>{$content}</div>',
        player:     'html',
        height:     500,
        width:      1200,
        handleOversize: 'drag'
        }); 
    });
});       
</script>";

return $output;
```

Comment: `it's a very bad practice.` welcome to the Wordpress plugins world.

Comment: I'm no WordPress expert myself, but I just did a quick google search and found this: [Adding Scripts Properly to WordPress](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/05/07/adding-scripts-properly-to-wordpress-part-2-javascript-localization/). Perhaps that article may guide to a more clean approach?

Comment: What i meant: don't look for good practice in wordpress plugins. :) It's different world

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I figured that if I posted this I would get a remark about it not being good practice to output JavaScript with PHP.  I read over that article you mentioned, and if I use the method from the article I don't have this problem, however, I need to run this script multiple times using different variables each time (as it will be applied every time the editor uses the shortcode).  I am having trouble adapting the method from the article to allow me to do that.  Thanks for the article though -- it will be very useful to me in the future -- I have been wondering how to do that!

Comment: Glad to hear. On that last note, how about you set an object and you just set some properties on that object on the template, and then use them on that function? That way your javascript code will be using dynamic properties, depending on how you set said object on your template. Not sure if I explained myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `content: '<div id=\'popup{$photo_id}\' class=\'popup\'>{$content}</div>'` is a problem because the value for the parameter `content` is being interpreted as `'<div id=\'`. It stops at the next quote mark. If your version of PHP is not liking this (as it seems), you should separate this part of the variable by concatenation.

```
    $output="<script type='text/javascript' >
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#photo{$photo_id}').on('click', function(){ 
      Shadowbox.open({";

$output .= "
        content: '<div id=\"popup{$photo_id}\" class=\"popup\">{$content}</div>,'";

$output .= "
        player:     'html',
        height:     500,
        width:      1200,
        handleOversize: 'drag'
        }); 
    });
});       
</script>";

return $output;
```

It's also better practice to use ' for your echo statements and " for everything inside, when possible, to avoid dealing with quote escaping, e.g. `echo 'My friend says "hello", Tom.';`

Answer (score 0):

One of WordPress' automatic formatting function, the wpautop filter was causing the problem.

I was already using Chris Coyer's "raw" shortcode, (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/disable-automatic-formatting-using-a-shortcode/) so the answer was as simple as wrapping the script in [raw][/raw] shortcodes before outputting it back into the content area.

Ha ha ha!